# how to change the url for SolrNet Client

Tags: solr, solrnet, solrj

I am a newbie in solrnet and my question is how to change the url for SolrNet Client.

I found this on wiki

initailizing code

`Startup.Init<Product>("http://localhost:8983/solr");`

invoking code

`var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Product>>();`

but I dont know how to change the url , could someone tell me how to do this, I am really thanks.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more? The URL is right there, you can replace it with your own. Or is that not what you meant?

Comment: I am sorry, My English is not very good...

Comment: my meaning is I want to change solr instance at runtime, there is a config file in my project, it configs solr instance url, if it chances, I want to create a new Solr Server Object, but in SolrNet, it uses init method, if I invoke init method twice, it will throw an exception, so what should I do? thanks :)

Comment: Why does the URL change at runtime in your application? Do you have multiple instances/cores? Have you seen http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/MultiCoreAccess ?

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be changed with existing SOLRNet code as it is implemented on singleton pattern.

You have to download the code from [github](https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet).

Currently following exception has been thrown 
*"Key ... already registered in container"*. You can change code in a way that it will always create new instance. (by pass Singleton pattern)

Comment: @illu, I have found a solution. Before initializing call this method.  `Startup.InitContainer();`

Answer (score 0):

The default request handler is "/select". So SolrNet will send your requests to

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/select
```

If you wish to invoke a different request handler, you will need to get a instance of the SolrQueryExecuter and set the Handler property, accordingly.

Assuming you have a request handler named "/browse":

```
Startup.Init<Product>("http://localhost:8983/solr"); 
var executor = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrQueryExecuter<Product>>() as SolrQueryExecuter<Product>;

if (executor != null)
{
    executor.Handler = "/browse";
}
```